# Fix dates in CSV files using powershell, convert to UK format and add second if missing

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have the below csv data (sample), as you can see the date is in US format (MM/dd/yyyy) and sometimes the seconds (:ss) is missing. I would like to fix it so the date is in UK format (dd/MM/yyyy) and if the seconds is missing in the time, then add :00

```
Time,Incident
03/25/2021 12:59:49,INC18072411
04/03/2021 13:00,INC17989469
05/14/2021 13:01:57,INC17987450
05/28/2021 13:02:56,INC18000995
06/01/2021 13:06,INC17990104
06/06/2021 13:06:23,INC17983804
07/19/2021 13:07,INC17973858
08/08/2021 13:08:04,INC17987287
09/20/2021 13:08:19,INC17986031
10/10/2021 13:13,INC17926602
```

I have tried the below

```
Import-Csv $CsvPath | ForEach-Object { ([datetime]::ParseExact($_.Time,"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",$null)).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss') } | Export-Csv $CsvUpdatedPath -NoTypeInformation
```

but get error on records where the seconds is missing:

> Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not
> recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Ah, now I see. I missed the casting to `[string[]]` in my answer.  (corrected now).  .Net expects a **strongly typed** string array there (must implement [System.Collections.IEnumerable]). Just change to `[string[]]$formats = 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'` and you will see it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact) on multiple formats provided you also specify more parameters:

```
# .Net expects a strongly typed string array 
# (must implement [System.Collections.IEnumerable]), so cast to [string[]]
[string[]]$formats = 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\theTimes.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Time, $formats, [cultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, 'None').ToString('dd\/MM\/yyyy H:mm:ss')
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Time = $date
        Incident = $_.Incident
    }
}
```

Given your example data this would yield

```
Time                Incident   
----                --------   
25/03/2021 12:59:49 INC18072411
03/04/2021 13:00:00 INC17989469
14/05/2021 13:01:57 INC17987450
28/05/2021 13:02:56 INC18000995
01/06/2021 13:06:00 INC17990104
06/06/2021 13:06:23 INC17983804
19/07/2021 13:07:00 INC17973858
08/08/2021 13:08:04 INC17987287
20/09/2021 13:08:19 INC17986031
10/10/2021 13:13:00 INC17926602
```

Comment: Ui ... I didn't know that you can use multiple formats. That looks more sophisticated and robust. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, couldn't get it to work. kept getting error: Exception calling "ParseExact" with "4" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: If you need further help you should share the sanitized but exact code you used and the complete error message (formatted as code, please).

Comment: @TripToBelize As [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74190757/fix-dates-in-csv-files-using-powershell-convert-to-uk-format-and-add-second-if/74192156?noredirect=1#comment131067991_74192156) commented. Please show the exact string you needed to parse and the error message in full. Also please tell us what Powershell version you use.

Comment: Added code and error in my original post

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you could add the missing seconds before parsing the input string to a `[DateTime]` type.

```
$InputData = @'
Time,Incident
03/25/2021 12:59:49,INC18072411
04/03/2021 13:00,INC17989469
05/14/2021 13:01:57,INC17987450
05/28/2021 13:02:56,INC18000995
06/01/2021 13:06,INC17990104
06/06/2021 13:06:23,INC17983804
07/19/2021 13:07,INC17973858
08/08/2021 13:08:04,INC17987287
09/20/2021 13:08:19,INC17986031
10/10/2021 13:13,INC17926602
'@ |
ConvertFrom-Csv

$InputData |
ForEach-Object {
    $TimeString = $_.Time -replace '(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2})$', '$1:00'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name     = ([datetime]::ParseExact($TimeString, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", $null)).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss')
        Incident = $_.Incident
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly but would be interesting to know why I couldnt get Theos solution to work